# Explanation of a single line of code for prime numbers

Tags: r, function, loops

Hi i just need some help understanding this line of code from a function to get prime numbers (see below for the whole function):

```
if (i == 2L || all(i %% 2L:ceiling(sqrt(i)) != 0))
```

What does `i == 2L` do as well as `ceiling(sqrt(i))`. This function basically just generates a vector of prime numbers or just returns the last prime number in the vector. I don't quite understand what those 2 sections are used for.

Normally i would just check for a prime number like this `all(i %% 2:(i-1) !=0)` So why  are those two elements changed in the code?

```
get_prime <- function(n, all = TRUE, i = 1, primes = c()){
  if ( n <= 0) {
    stop("Not a valid number")
  }

  if (length(primes) < n) {
    if (i == 2L || all(i %% 2L:ceiling(sqrt(i)) != 0)) {
      get_prime(n, all = all, i = i + 1, primes = c(primes, i))
    } else {
      get_prime(n, all = all, i = i + 1, primes = primes)
    }
  } else {
    if (all) {
      return(primes)
    } else {
      return(tail(primes, 1))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok i understand `ceiling(sqrt(i))` as just the number you should check up to for primes but just `i == 2L` i sitll dont understand

Comment: `2L` is the number 2 as class `integer` as opposed to `numeric`, which you get if you type `2`. Not sure why'd you need it, though

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you had to check if q=1,000,001 was a prime number.
The simplest way to do this is to check if any integer in [2, 1000000] is a factor of q.
Suppose a factor, f, of q does exist and it is not in [2, ceiling(sqrt(q))].
So f > ceiling(sqrt(q)) and q/f <= q/sqrt(q) = sqrt(q)
So whatever q/f is, it lies in [2, ceiling(sqrt(q))].

That's why you only need to check up to ceiling(sqrt(q))